# Include/Require non php file

Tags: php

I know that PHP's `include/require` statements can append other .php files into the script, either from a local path or an url.

Today i tried to include and also to require a .ddf (a text file), and it worked, with no errors or warnings. Then PHP actually executed some code that was in that file!

After that i went into the PHP's documentation for `include` to see if including non-php files is fully supported and safe. Turns out that, the documentation barely mentions this procedure (`include 'file.txt';  // Works.`) that's it.

So i'm asking you guys, Is including non-php files safe? Also is it a bad practice?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: @1nflktd I don't, i'm just curious :) And I'm guessing you down voted? why?

Comment: It's as safe as it is sensical to do it.

Comment: If file is created by you then no problem.

Comment: There's no reason to do it. You're also losing the syntax highlighting that you get with the correct extension, which could end up being problematic when you want to edit the other file.

Comment: @Adrao no, I did not downvoted, I just wanted to know the context of doing this, thinking in a better way of doing that.

Comment: I'll give you a reason why. We've been using Laravel Forge. There's a `.env` file that can be edited in the Forge UI. We've placed some database PHP info and Drupal settings in there. Instead of SSH'ing into the server, we can make site-specific modifications through a UI, but the filename is not suffixed with `.php`. It's a valid question. I upvoted it back to zero.

Comment: I've long included a PHP file that has some PHP code in it (within PHP tags) but also some JavaScript, within script tags.  It works fine.  The reason I did this is because the JavaScript pertains to the PHP.  However, I don't like it, so I'm separating out the JavaScript into a separate file, but the point is, it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just want to say that it is completely unsafe. While yes, as long as you trust the page, you technically could do this. But the page when pulled up directly in the browser isn't parsed as php. Anyone who goes directly to the file in the web server, whether guessing or you made a framework or they just know some file names, would see the complete source of the file. Exposing your site and possibly releasing sensitive information like database credentials. Another thing to think about is that people are usually pretty good about not allowing *.php files to be uploaded to their site, but just imagine you are allowing other files to be included and someone uploads a text file named "someImage.jpg" with php script in it and for some dumb reason you include it. People now have a way to execute scripts on your server. Likely including calling shell commands (exec). It used to be common practice to use *.inc files to specify includes but that has been considered bad for quite a long time.

Answer (score 4):

It is not advisable to include txt files in php scripts. Instead, you should use  [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).